# Need help in extracting key list from List of dictionaries and corresponding counts using Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, function, dictionary

Hi I am looking to extract list of all keys from a List of dictionaries and their corresponding counts using Python. Used below code but counden't do it can some one help me in this regard

The Data looks like this,

```
people = [{'name': "Tom", 'age': 10, "city" : "NewYork"},
{'name': "Mark", 'age': 5, "country" : "Japan"},
{'name': "Pam", 'age': 7, "city" : "London"},
{'name': "Tom", 'hight': 163, "city" : "California"},
{'name': "Lena", 'weight': 45, "country" : "Italy"},
{'name': "Ben", 'age': 17, "city" : "Colombo"},
{'name': "Lena", 'gender': "Female", "country" : "Italy"},
{'name': "Ben", 'gender': "Male", "city" : "Colombo"}]


def search(name):
    p_count = 0
    for p in people:
        if p['name'] == name:
            p_count = p_count+1
            return p, p_count
search("Pam")

def search1(list_dict):
    for i in list_dict:
        def getList(i):
            return i.keys()
search1(people)
```

I want out put like the following,
name: 8, age: 4, City:3, Country: 2 etc..

I am new to this can some one help me in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a temporary dictionary to hold the count result, and for each key in each dictionary of the list, increase the the count by 1 using `dict.get` with default value as `0`, finally return this dictionary.

```py
def getKeyCount(lst):
    out = {}
    for d in lst:
        for k in d.keys():
            out[k] = out.get(k, 0) + 1
    return out

getKeyCount(people)
#output
{'name': 8, 'age': 4, 'city': 5, 'country': 3, 'hight': 1, 'weight': 1, 'gender': 2}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that really helped...and in any way can I get the sub count say for example New York:1, London:2

Comment: That is not key, that is value, so you need to count the values.

Comment: yaa both keys and values ... I have to count in some cases

Comment: That becomes a new question, you can ask on Stackoverflow, someone will definitely answer it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a hash table, and iterate over the keys of each

```
hash = {}
for d in list_dict:
    for k in d.keys():
        if k not in hash:
            hash[k] = 0
        hash[k] += 1

print(hash)
```

Comment: 1) Please explain how this is a hash table.  This is really just another `dict`.  2) This is overwriting the builtin `hash` function.  Should use a different variable name. 3) This is essentially a copy of the [answer already provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68346247/6340496).